# SQL . Timestamp issue with max value

Tags: sql, sqlite, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello I have a sql script like this. My intention of the script is to produce out the highest value of today. However the script produce out an unintended result. Can anyone help me look at my code and see what is wrong with it ?

Script

```
SELECT   MAX(Value),
         TIMESTAMP,
         fooditem,
         cashcurren
FROM     farm1
WHERE    r.timestamp > 1405987200
         AND r.timestamp <= (1405987200 + 86400)
         AND fooditem = '2'
         AND cashcurren = '10'
GROUP BY timestamp, fooditem, cashcurren;
```

The Unintended Result

```
Value Timestamp    fooditem   cashcurren

 200 1406029354          2         10
  84 1406034965          2         10
 536 1406034973          2         10
  70 1406035006          2         10
  63 1406035025          2         10
```

The Result I want

Value Timestamp    fooditem   cashcurren

```
 536 1406034973          2         10
```

Basically I want my Oracle SQL to return back the highest value for food item #2 and cashcurrency #10 from the timestamp 1405987200 to 1405987200 + 86400 (the timestamp is the whole day of 7/22 in this case).

Comment: If you look at that result every single row has a different timestamp. You selected the max value for each timestamp, fooditem, and cashcurren combination (your group by clause has all 3). The reason you have 5 rows rather than 1 is because each of those 5 rows has a different timestamp. You grouped by timestamp. You can instead not aggregate and order by value descending and limit 1 or use a join with an inline view or use a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Value, TIMESTAMP, fooditem, cashcurren
  FROM farm1 f
 WHERE timestamp between 1405987200 and (1405987200 + 86400)
   AND fooditem = '2'
   AND cashcurren = '10'
 where value =
       (select max(x.value)
          from farm1 x
         where x.timestamp between 1405987200 and (1405987200 + 86400)
           and x.fooditem = f.fooditem
           and x.cashcurren = f.cashcurren)
```

Using max(value) and grouping by timestamp does not lead to any aggregation and does not make sense. (there is likely only one per timestamp)

The above query uses a subquery to select the max value for the given timestamp range, fooditem, and cashcurren, and then feeds that value to the query in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   MAX(Value),
         TIMESTAMP,
         fooditem,
         cashcurren
FROM     farm1
WHERE    r.timestamp > 1405987200
         AND r.timestamp <= (1405987200 + 86400)
         AND fooditem = '2'
         AND cashcurren = '10'
GROUP BY timestamp, fooditem, cashcurren
order by 1 desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT   d.Value, d.TIMESTAMP, d.fooditem, d.cashcurren
    FROM     (SELECT   MAX(Value) AS 'Value',
                   TIMESTAMP,
                   fooditem,
                   cashcurren
          FROM     farm1
          WHERE    r.timestamp > 1405987200
                   AND r.timestamp <= (1405987200 + 86400)
                   AND fooditem = '2'
                   AND cashcurren = '10'
          GROUP BY timestamp, fooditem, cashcurren) AS d
    ORDER BY d.Valuse DESC limit 1;
```