# SQL . Selecting highest value from a range of timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a code like this. My intended result is to grab the highest value from a set range of timestamps. I'm not sure why this isn't working. I am using Oracles SQL 10. Thank you in advance for your help.

Code

```
 SELECT value, timestamp
      FROM farm1 f
     WHERE timestamp between 1405987200 and (1405987200 + 86400)
     where value =
           (select max(x.value)
             from farm1 x
             where x.timestamp between 1405987200 and (1405987200 + 86400);
```

Expected Results

```
 TIMESTAMP        VALUE
----------    ----------

1406056898         8.09
```

Results it is producing

```
 TIMESTAMP        VALUE
----------    ----------
1405992437         6.49
1406056898         8.09
1406055371         9.4
1406071600         1.12
```

In addition is there a way to grab today's timestamps only without using unix time such as 1405992437  ?

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24897127/2589202)?

Comment: your query is wrong, there are 2 where clauses... it doesnt compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(value)
FROM farm1
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1405987200 AND (1405987200 + 86400)
```

?

And for your second question, do you mean using human readable comparisons? You can always use `WHERE TO_DATE(timestamp,...)` but I'm not sure about how your indexes would react after that.